# Unit Testing NAudio with ManualResetEvent Locks Up Test

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, naudio

Alright, I'm trying to unit test NAudio against a wrapper I created for a recording session, here is the code that starts and stops a recording session ...

```
public void StartRecording(string claimNo, string ip_no, string ip_name)
{
    if (this.IsRecording)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.Recordings.Add(new RecordingTrack(claimNo, ip_no, ip_name));
    if (this.MicrophoneLevel == default(float))
    {
        this.MicrophoneLevel = .75f;
    }

    _aggregator.Reset();

    _input = new WaveIn();
    _input.WaveFormat = _waveFormat;

    _input.DataAvailable += (s, args) =>
        {
            _writer.Write(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded);
            byte[] buffer = args.Buffer;
            for (int index = 0; index < args.BytesRecorded; index += 2)
            {
                short sample = (short)((buffer[index + 1] << 8) | buffer[index + 0]);
                float sample32 = sample / 32768f;
                _aggregator.Add(sample32);
            }

            if (this.DataAvailable != null)
            {
                this.DataAvailable(s, args);
            }

            if (!this.IsRecording)
            {
                _writer.Close();
                _writer.Dispose();
                _writer = null;
            }
        };
    _input.RecordingStopped += (s, args) =>
        {
            _input.Dispose();
            _input = null;

            if (this.RecordingStopped != null)
            {
                this.RecordingStopped(s, args);
            }
        };

    _writer = new WaveFileWriter(this.CurrentRecording.FileName, _input.WaveFormat);

    _input.StartRecording();
    this.IsRecording = true;
}

public void StopRecording()
{
    if (!this.IsRecording)
    {
        return;
    }

    this.CurrentRecording.Stop();

    this.IsRecording = false;
    _input.StopRecording();
}
```

... and below is my unit test. I'm using a `ManualResetEvent` to assert the success of the event being fired and it's declared like this ...

```
private ManualResetEvent _eventRaised = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

... however, the issue is that the test below simply locks up and the event is never fired. **Can you confirm that the issue is that the `WaitOne` is not allowing the event to fire because it's locking the same thread?**

```
bool success = false;
_eventRaised.Reset();

var target = new RecordingSession();
target.StartRecording("1", "01", "Test Name");

target.RecordingStopped += (s, args) =>
    {
        success = (target.CurrentRecording.Duration.TotalSeconds > 4);
        _eventRaised.Set();
    };

Thread.Sleep(4000);
target.StopRecording();

_eventRaised.WaitOne();

Assert.IsTrue(success);
```

**And if so, can you help me with this test?** I need some enlightenment.

I've used the `ManualResetEvent` many times to test events on other classes and it's worked, but something is different here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never get an event because the default constructor of WaveIn uses windowed callbacks, and you are not running your unit test on a GUI thread. You should use WaveInEvent instead to work on a non-gui thread. In the very latest NAudio code an InvalidOperationException should be thrown to prevent you from making this mistake.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that the event is fired before you have connected to it if the `_input` member is working in its own thread. Hence, the manual reset event will never get set, causing it to wait forever/lock up your unit test.

So perhaps try re-order your definition to:

```
target.RecordingStopped += (s, args) =>     
{         
    success = (target.CurrentRecording.Duration.TotalSeconds > 4);         
    _eventRaised.Set();     
};

target.StartRecording("1", "01", "Test Name");
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it didn't work friend, sorry. Nevertheless a better approach and I'll be sticking with it!